# How to change given input radio value with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, input

I have a basic radio button and want to change its value. I tried this but it did not work. It gave me an `[object Object]` error.

```
<input type="radio" name="myname" value="horse">
```

```js
var myval = $("input:radio").val(["cat"]);
alert(myval);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If it's for debugage, better use console.log, instead of alert. console.log() display object propery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rko6L8b6/)

```
var myval = $("input:radio").val("cat"); // remove []
alert(myval.val()); // alert the value, not the jquery selector
```

Note - `$("input:radio")` will select all the radio buttons on the page which may not be what you want all the time.

- If you are targeting a selected radio button from a specific group of radio buttons with the same name, use `$("input:radio[name=groupname]")`.
- Or else, if you are targeting a specific radio button out of all the radio buttons, use an ID (since IDs are unique) like this `$("#radioButtonId1")`

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input:radio')
```

returns all the radio buttons in your page as an object.

```
$('input:radio').val("cat")
```

will set the value of **all** radio buttons.

```
$("input:radio[name=myname]").val("cat");
```

will set the value of the radio button to "cat".
Note that multiple radio buttons can have the same name

```
<input type="radio" name="myname" value="horse" id="myradiobtn">
```

```
$("#myradiobtn").val("cat");
```

will only change the value of this specific radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it like this:

```
$('input[name=myname]').val("cat");
```

Answer (score 1):

For change value of radio.

```
$("input:radio[name=myname]").val("cat");
```

To get value from radio.

```
var myval = $("input:radio[name=myname]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use val without [ ] for single values and use myval.val() to get its value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="myname" value="horse">

<script>
var myval = $("input:radio").val("cat");
alert(myval.val());
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="myname" value="horse">

var myval = $("input:radio[name=myname]").val("cat");
alert(myval.val());
```

remove [] around cat as you want to set value to the string cat, not an array containing the string cat.

select $("input:radio[name=myname]") as it provides more clarity it doesn't matter in this example but it's good practice

alert is giving you [Object object] because it can only output strings so you need to get myval.val().

I suggest using console.log as it will be cleaner and offers the ability to delve into an object if you accidentally select the wrong part of something.